# Flatten a nested JSON structure and append property name in mongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have an object like this

```
{
    "testing": {
      "total": 360,
      "status": "testing",
      "books": [
        {
          "book": "john goes to school",
          "authors": [
            "john@gmail.com"
          ]
        }
      ],
      
    },
    "dev": {
      "total": 863,
      "status": "dev",
      "books": [
        {
          "book": "bob makes a book",
          "authors": [
            "bob@gmail.com",
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "prod": {
      "total": 1,
      "status": "prod",
      "flags": [
        {
          "book": "nancy writes an essay",
          "authors": [
            "nancy@gmail.com"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

and I want to flatten it to look like this:

```
{
   "books":[
      {
         "book":"john goes to school",
         "authors":[
            "john@gmail.com"
         ],
         "status":"testing"
      },
      {
         "book":"bob makes a book",
         "authors":[
            "bob@gmail.com"
         ],
         "status":"dev"
      },
      {
         "book":"nancy writes an essay",
         "authors":[
            "nancy@gmail.com"
         ],
         "status":"prod"
      }
   ]
}
```

So far the best i got to have it looking close to that is using this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      dev: "$dev.books",
      test: "$test.books",
      prod: "$prod.books"
    }
  }
```

I tried using combination of $unwind, $map, and $reduce but not sure how to make sense of it. Basically, I've been trying to flatten the array, and have the status appended to each record
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this aggregation -

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "arr": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$arr"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "arr.v.books.status": "$arr.v.status"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "books": {
        "$addToSet": "$arr.v.books"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eRG6pvw3PqR)

Comment: this works great. what would the $set stage equivalent be for Mongo 3? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Try $addFields instead of $set